# Graphviz drawing two arrows intead of one

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a strange result trying to make a simple graph using graphviz. **Two arrows** are drawn between `3` and `4` **instead of one**. I can't figure out why, if it is a bug or if I've done something wrong. Here is a minimal example, anything I remove makes the problem dissapear:

```
digraph dia {
    newrank=true;

    1 -> 2;

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label = "1";
        3 -> 5;
        3 -> 6;
        5 -> 6
    }
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label = "2";
        4;
    }
    3 -> 4;

    {rank="same"; 2; 5; 6;}
    {rank="same"; 3; 4}
}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: Graphviz output]

My actual graph is larger than that, and I need `newrank` property.

I think I have the lastest version of graphviz...

`dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)`

Thanks for any help !

Comment: That looks like a bug to me - same here, and all attempts to remedy the situation failed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also noticed some strange things going on in graphviz when clusters are being used (especially in combination with `rank=same`. So probably a bug, yes.

In your situation simply adding a port to one of the problematic nodes fixes the problem:

`3:e -> 4;`